# Display 5-digit base unicode character from the Entypo font

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I'm using the Entypo font in my iPhone app but it's working fine only for some characters. I'm not able to display icons using five-digit unicode values.

I found some information on the Web telling this is due to the UTF encoding supported on iOS (and within other languages too) and the 5-digit unicode values should be splitted in two values.

But I'm not found a clear how-to description or a code sample.

My code to display a Entypo symbol is something like this:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u25B6"];
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Entypo" size:200];
```

If I replace the unicode value by "\u1F342" which is the icon leaf in the Entypo font then a non-valid character is displayed.

If you already have encountered this issue, perhaps you could help me to save time.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several searches I finally found a solution being easy to use in the different cases: symbol encoded up to 4 digits and more than 4 digits.

I defined a NSString category as follows:

```
#import "NSString+Extension.h"

@implementation NSString (Extension)

/**
 * Convert a UTF8 symbol to a string which can directly be used as text in a label view for instance, for which the right font has been specified.
 *
 * The method can be used for both cases
 *  . the symbol is defined as a const char with a maximum of 4 digits. In this case the first parameter must be 0 and the second is used. Example: NSString *symbolString = [NSString symbolStringfromUnicode:0 orChar:"\uE766"]
 *  . the symbol is defined as an integer with hexadecimal notation. It can be have either less or more than 4 digits. In this case, only the first parameter is used. Example : NSString *prefixSymbol = [NSString symbolStringfromUnicode:0x1F464 orChar:nil];
 *
 * @param symbolUnicode     symbol to convert defined as int
 * @param symbolChar        symbol to convert defined as const char *
 *
 */

+ (NSString *)symbolStringfromUnicode:(int)symbolUnicode orChar:(const char *)symbolChar
{
    NSString *symbolString;
    if (symbolUnicode == 0) {
        symbolString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:symbolChar];
    }
    else {
        int unicode = symbolUnicode;
        symbolString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&unicode length:sizeof(unicode) encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    }

    return symbolString;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [unicode page for that character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f342/index.htm), you'll see that its UTF-8 encoding is `0xF0 0x9F 0x8D 0x82` - that's what you should be using:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\uf0\u9f\u8d\u82"];
```

Note: totally untested.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found another way avoiding to have searching the UTF-8 encoding on another Web site.